# String.Format alternative in C++

Tags: c#, c++, string, string-formatting

I don't have much experience working with C++. Rather I have worked more in C# and so, I wanted to ask my question by relating to what I would have done in there. I have to generate a specific format of the string, which I have to pass to another function. In C#, I would have easily generated the string through the below simple code.

```
string a = "test";
string b = "text.txt";
string c = "text1.txt";

String.Format("{0} {1} > {2}", a, b, c);
```

By generating such an above string, I should be able to pass this in `system()`. However, `system` only accepts `char*`

I am on `Win32 C++` (not C++/CLI), and cannot use `boost` since it would include too much inclusion of all the files for a project which itself is very small. Something like `sprintf()` looks useful to me, but `sprintf` does not accept `string` as the `a`, `b` and `c` parameters. Any suggestions how I can generate these formatted strings to pass to system in my program?

Comment: you know that boost won't add any dependencies to your binaries, right? (It will, of course add dependencies to the source)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` in combination with `std::string.c_str()`.

`c_str()` returns a `const char*` and works with `sprintf`:

```
string a = "test";
string b = "text.txt";
string c = "text1.txt";
char* x = new char[a.length() + b.length() + c.length() + 32];

sprintf(x, "%s %s > %s", a.c_str(), b.c_str(), c.c_str() );

string str = x;
delete[] x;
```

or you can use a pre-allocated `char` array if you know the size:

```
string a = "test";
string b = "text.txt";
string c = "text1.txt";
char x[256];

sprintf(x, "%s %s > %s", a.c_str(), b.c_str(), c.c_str() );
```

Comment: Shouldn't {0}, {1}, {2} be %s ? And should I delete this char* x after the operation or it doesn't matter?

Comment: What are {0}, {1}, {2} in sprintf? What is delete[x]?

Comment: @user1240679 that was a typo, se corrected version. You should delete the char* if allocated with `new`, otherwise it's a memory leak.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I would seriously advise a combination of `std::vector` and `snprintf` to avoid both leaks and buffer overflows. See [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

Answer (score 46):

The C++ way would be to use a `std::stringstream` object as:

```
std::stringstream fmt;
fmt << a << " " << b << " > " << c;
```

The C way would be to use `sprintf`.

The C way is difficult to get right since:

- It is type unsafe
- Requires buffer management

Of course, you may want to fall back on the C way if performance is an issue (imagine you are creating fixed-size million little `stringstream` objects and then throwing them away).

Comment: `system(fmt)` gives me an erros saying no suitable conversion between `stringstream` to `char*`

Comment: system(fmt.str().c_str()) should probably do it. Note that on windows at least, if you call system() and you get errors even though the command and its arguments are correct and properly-quoted, surround the whole thing in quotes and it'll work.

Comment: Two things to note: 1) `system` is implementation defined -- so do not use it if you want to keep your code portable. 2) As others have mentioned, use `fmt.str().c_str()` to get to the `char *` (C-style string) representation of the string.

Answer (score 32):

For the sake of completeness, you may use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string a = "a", b = "b", c = "c";
    // apply formatting
    std::stringstream s;
    s << a << " " << b << " > " << c;
    // assign to std::string
    std::string str = s.str();
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

---

Or (in this case) `std::string`'s very own string concatenation capabilities:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string a = "a", b = "b", c = "c";
    std::string str = a + " " + b + " > " + c;
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator+

---

If you really want to go the C way, here you are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    std::string a = "a", b = "b", c = "c";
    const char fmt[] = "%s %s > %s";
    // use std::vector for memory management (to avoid memory leaks)
    std::vector<char>::size_type size = 256;
    std::vector<char> buf;
    do {
        // use snprintf instead of sprintf (to avoid buffer overflows)
        // snprintf returns the required size (without terminating null)
        // if buffer is too small initially: loop should run at most twice
        buf.resize(size+1);
        size = std::snprintf(
                &buf[0], buf.size(),
                fmt, a.c_str(), b.c_str(), c.c_str());
    } while (size+1 > buf.size());
    // assign to std::string
    std::string str = &buf[0];
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

---

Since C++11, you can "simplify" this to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    std::string a = "a", b = "b", c = "c";
    const char fmt[] = "%s %s > %s";
    // can use std::string as buffer directly (since C++11)
    std::string::size_type size = 256;
    std::string str;
    do {
        str.resize(size+1);
        // use snprintf instead of sprintf (to avoid buffer overflows)
        // snprintf returns the required size (without terminating null)
        // if buffer is too small initially: loop should run at most twice
        size = std::snprintf(
                &str[0], str.size(),
                fmt, a.c_str(), b.c_str(), c.c_str());
    } while (size+1 > str.size());
    // can strip off null-terminator, as std::string adds their own
    str.resize(size);
    // done
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

For reference:

- [Directly write into char* buffer of std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200665/directly-write-into-char-buffer-of-stdstring)

---

Then, there's the [Boost Format Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/format/doc/format.html). For the sake of your example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

int main() {
    std::string a = "a", b = "b", c = "c";
    // apply format
    boost::format fmt = boost::format("%s %s > %s") % a % b % c; 
    // assign to std::string
    std::string str = fmt.str();
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The OP had mentioned that `boost` can't be used :/

Answer (score 19):

In addition to options suggested by others I can recommend the [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) which implements string formatting similar to [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) in Python and `String.Format` in C#. Here's an example:

```
std::string a = "test";
std::string b = "text.txt";
std::string c = "text1.txt";
std::string result = fmt::format("{0} {1} > {2}", a, b, c);
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, the [Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29) way would be to use [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/format/):

```
cout << boost::format("%s %s > %s") % a % b % c;
```

Take your pick. The Boost solution has the advantage of type safety with the `sprintf` format (for those who find the `<<` syntax a bit clunky).

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned the C++ way is using stringstreams.

```
#include <sstream>

string a = "test";
string b = "text.txt";
string c = "text1.txt";

std::stringstream ostr;
ostr << a << " " << b << " > " << c;
```

Note that you can get the C string from the string stream object like so.

```
std::string formatted_string = ostr.str();
const char* c_str = formatted_string.c_str();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just concatenate the strings and build a command line.

```
std::string command = a + ' ' + b + " > " + c;
system(command.c_str());
```

You don't need any extra libraries for this.

Comment: As far as I am aware C++ does not optimise this, so this would copy the the string for each operation, first creating `a + ' '` then, `a + ' ' + b`, etc.