# C++ file naming using variables

Tags: c++, file, filenames

Basically I want to be able to create a file name using two variables defined during the program (value unknown to programmer). I can do it using just one variable (i.e (username + ".txt")) , but for some reason using two messes it up.

This is my code.

```
void User::setTicket(std::string username, int i)
{
    std::ofstream fout (username + "Ticket" + i + ".txt");

    // Some code

        fout.close();
}
```

int i is essentially a counting digit initialised in a loop in main, so everytime the loop goes round setTicket is called, and hopefully the resulting files would be called

user1Ticket1.txt
user1Ticket2.txt
user1Ticket3.txt
etc

Comment: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410023/string-format-alternative-in-c)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numerical types can't be implicitly converted to, or directly appended to, strings.

In C++11 or later, there's a library function to convert them:

```
std::ofstream fout (username + "Ticket" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt");
```

Historically, string-streams can build strings from arbitrary types:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << username << "Ticket" << i << ".txt";
std::ofstream fout (ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: brilliant, the second version worked, I assume that means Visual Studio 2010 uses an older version of C++

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the integer to a string using `std::to_string(i)` (c++11) in order to use operator + of a string

also see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are 3 ways to do it.

In case you have a c++11 compiler, you can the std::to_string(i), as @Dlotan pointed:

```
std::ofstream fout(username + "Ticket" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt");
```

In case you want to use boost:

```
std::ofstream fout(username + "Ticket" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i) + ".txt");
```

In case you don't have a c++11 compiler neither want to use boost:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << i;
std::ofstream fout(username + "Ticket" + ss.str() + ".txt");
```